# Sending additional data with multipart

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I am using `apache-commons-fileupload` to get file from `client` to the `server`.(using `JSP` and `Servlet`).

**JSP/HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="GetFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="datafile">
<input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

**Servlet: GetFile**

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("text1"));
```

I am able to upload the file to the server, but I am not able to get the value of `text1` in the `servlet` (I am getting `null` value of `text1` in the `servlet`), I need this `textfield` in the form to submit some additional information while uploading it to the `server`.

- Is `enctype="multipart/form-data"` option of form doesn't allow other
  form data to be submited? if it doesn't allow it then what are the other options I have to send this additional `textfield` to the `server`.
- Or is there any other problem in my code?

Comment: you can use javascript or jquery to set the data in textfield

Comment: @Biswajit that has nothing to do with the problem of the OP.

Comment: Could it be that you have more input fields with `name="text1"`? Cause `request.getParameter(...)` only gets the first value of a parameter, if you have more with the same `name` attribute the first one is might empty and therefore null.

Comment: @Biswajit Why in the world do you think it will help to set the field using js/jquery?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is `enctype="multipart/form-data"` option of form doesn't allow other
> form data to be submited? if it doesn't allow it then what are the
> other options I have to send this additional textfield to the server.

No there is no issue with using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. You can get other fields then file in such form.

> Or is there any other problem in my code?

Yes, as for now. While using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` you can not directly get parameters by using `request.getParameter(name);`. While using it, form fields aren't available as parameter of the request, they are included in the stream, so you can not get it the normal way. You can find a way to do this in [the docs of using commons-fileupload#*Processing the uploaded items*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html#Processing_the_uploaded_items).

Answer (score 14):

Well the parameters are  not lost , its just that they are part of request Stream.

You have to get all the items from the Request and iterate and handle it accordingly based on their item type

```
List  items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

Heres how you can get it

```
// Process the uploaded items
Iterator iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {

      String name = item.getFieldName();//text1
      String value = item.getString();

    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I searched for an hour for my bug, here iis the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
MultipartRequest req = new MultipartRequest(request, UPLOAD_PATH, 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    out.print(req.getParameter("contractNo"));
    out.println("<BR>");
    Enumeration files = req.getFileNames();
    while (files.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = (String) files.nextElement();
        String filename = req.getFilesystemName(name);
        String type = req.getContentType(name);
        File uploadedFile = req.getFile("xlFile");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(UPLOAD_PATH + name, true);
        BufferedWriter out11 = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        String aLine = null;
        while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //Process each line and add output to Dest.txt file
            out11.write(aLine);
            out11.newLine();
        }

        // do not forget to close the buffer reader
        in.close();

        // close buffer writer
        out11.close();
    }
```

Above code will read file along with other form data just have a look at `req.getParameter();` method of`MultipartRequest req` object

Answer (score 0):

1. download the jar file com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest
2. import `com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest` in your servlet / .java file contained in `Web-Inf/classes`
3. in your servlets `doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {` method add

   MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request, "C:\SavingDirectory");

then call your variables from the form as below;

```
String pdate = m.getParameter("plandate");
```

and print them from the servlet like `out.println(pdate);`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to retrieve HTML form fields in Servlet is to use apache commons-fileupload 1.3 jar.

Using iterator iterate through multipart HTTPServletRequest and use a for loop to check if it isFormField(), then

```
   String item1=null,item2=null,item3=null;

    if(item.isFormField())
    {


        if(item.getFieldName().equals("field1"))
        {   
          item1=item.getString();
        }


        if(item.getFieldName().equals("field2"))
        {   
             item2=item.getString();
        }



        if(item.getFieldName().equals("field3"))
        {   
             item3=item.getString();
        }


    }
```

and your HTML file should be like this

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="servletname" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="field1">
<input type="text" name="field2">
<input type="text" name="field3">
<input type="file" name="filetoupload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```