# File Upload and other html controls

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, file-upload

My form has `<input type="file">` and other html controls. I am able to upload the file to the server. However when I tried to `request.getParameter("phone");` It will output phone = **null**.

When I remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, I am able to get phone. However, upload file does not work.

How can I get phone parameter and upload file work together?

Help will be appreciate and thanks in advance! :)

Below are my codes.

In **jsp**

```
<FORM NAME="InputForm" ACTION="servletname" METHOD="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<P><input type="text" name="phone">
<P><input type="file" name="filename">
<P><input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</FORM>
```

In **SERVLET**

```
String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
```

Comment: Please check the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105322/multipart-form-data-sending-additional-data which should be similar to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet container is not able to translate form parameters encoded with `multipart/form-data`.  You need to manually decode them or use a third-party library (Apache Commons FileUpload) to extract the form parameters.

Comment: FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {

      String name = item.getFieldName();//text1
      String value = item.getString();

    }

Comment: From the above codes, I found out from how retrieve from text 1. But what if I have more than 1 inputs ? How to I know that output is for this particular input?

Comment: I recommend searching or asking "How do I get text fields using Apache Commons FileUpload"