# jsp:getProperty null when enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute is used

Tags: java, jsp, java-8, servlet-3.0, tomcat8.5

According to [Sending additional data with multipart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105322/sending-additional-data-with-multipart), `request.getParameter;` cannot use with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. At process.jsp, I didn't use `request.getParameter`. But `jsp:getProperty` return null value. 
Removing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` works fine.
I would like to know how enctype="multipart/form-data" effects `jsp:setProperty and jsp:getProperty`. How they are connect? I know `jsp:setProperty` is not prefer way. 
As I am working with old code, no framework or not MVC is used. But I have to run with servlet 3.0 and tomcat 8.5. Is there any other way to pass data while using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to Jsp to Jsp?

form.jsp

```
<!--    <form action="process.jsp" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> -->
<!--    <form action="process.jsp" method="post"> -->
    <form action="process.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br> 
        Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br> 
        Email:<input type="text" name="email"><br> 
        File:<input type="file" name="fileName"><br> 
        <hr>
        <input type="submit" value="register">
    </form>
```

process.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="dao.User" scope="page">
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="bean"/>  
</jsp:useBean>  

Record:<br>  
<jsp:getProperty property="name" name="bean"/><br>  
<jsp:getProperty property="password" name="bean"/><br>  
<jsp:getProperty property="email" name="bean" /><br>
```

User.java

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String fileName;

// getter and setter...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out why `enctype="multipart/form-data"` not work with `jsp:setProperty and jsp:getProperty`. As I am running with tomcat, process.jsp was generated as process_jsp.java.

```
  dao.User bean = null;
  bean = (dao.User) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("bean", javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
  if (bean == null){
    bean = new dao.User();
    _jspx_page_context.setAttribute("bean", bean, javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
    out.write('\n');
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspect(_jspx_page_context.findAttribute("bean"), request);
    out.write(' ');
    out.write(' ');
    out.write('\n');
  }
```

According to above source code `org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspect` was called.

```
   public static void introspect(Object bean, ServletRequest request) throws JasperException
    {
        Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames();
        while ( e.hasMoreElements() ) {
            String name  = e.nextElement();
            String value = request.getParameter(name);
            introspecthelper(bean, name, value, request, name, true);
        }
    }
```

Above code map request parameters and names (bean property names) and then `introspecthelper` will be passed value to the appropriate setter methods by using `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke`.

When working with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, `Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames()` is the problem. No element was found, so `introspecthelper` is never executed.

Because `JspRuntimeLibrary.introspect` is static method. I cannot override its behavior. So, writing custom tag or following [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) is the only way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsp to upload file to server with other input field.

Ex.
index.jsp

```
<form action="upload.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

upload.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        File file;
        int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
        int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
        String filePath = "D:/";

        String contentType = request.getContentType();
        if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
            factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);
            try {
                List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<body>");
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();
                    if (!fi.isFormField()) {
                        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                        String fileName = fi.getName();
                        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
                        file = new File(filePath + fileName);
                        //fi.write(file);
                        out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + fileName + "<br>");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(fi.getFieldName() +":"+fi.getString());
                    }
                }
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        } else {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to include jar file commons-fileupload with servlet jar.